# Looking for rigor on details of a proof that a maximal ideal in $C[0,1]$ is of the form $M_\gamma=\{f \in R \mid f(\gamma)=0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be the ring of real-valued continuous functions on the closed unit interval. If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, prove that there exists a real number $\gamma \in [0,1]$ such that $M=M_\gamma=\{f \in R \mid f(\gamma)=0\}$.

Suppose that $M \subset R$ is a maximal ideal and that $M \ne M_\gamma$ for any $\gamma$. Then for all $\gamma \in [0,1]$ there exists a map $f_\gamma \in M$ such that $f_\gamma(\gamma) \ne 0$.

By continuity, if $f_\gamma$ does not vanish at $\gamma$, then there is an open ball $B_\gamma$ where $f_\gamma$ does not vanish. These open balls cover the compact set $[0, 1]$, hence some finite subset of them, say $B_{\gamma_1}, . . . , B_{\gamma_t}$ also covers [0, 1].

Now $f = f^2_{\gamma_1} + . . .+ f^2_{\gamma_t}$ is continuous and nowhere zero, so it is is unit in $R$. Since $f \in M$, we have that $M = R$.

---

Few remarks on this proof. First the part

> By continuity, if $f_\gamma$ does not vanish at $\gamma$, then there is an open ball $B_\gamma$ where $f_\gamma$ does not vanish.

seems a bit handwavy and I would like to know why is this true?

---

Second part is the usage of compactness, but the way the pulled $f = f^2_{\gamma_1} + . . . + f^2_{\gamma_t}$ out of thin air is not natural to me. Is there a natural way to think about this map? And why do we even need the finite subcover here?

---

Lastly how is a continuous nowhere zero function automatically a unit in $R$?

Comment: Isn't $f=f_{\gamma_1}^2+\ldots+f_{\gamma_n}^2$? In other words, shouldn't indexing start from $1$, not $2$?

Comment: You need the finite subcover to be sure that $f$ exists.  You can't be sure an infinite sum exists.  You can be sure a finite sum exists.  If $f$ is nowhere zero, then $\frac 1f$ is defined and continuous.  If $f(\gamma)= y \neq 0$, then set $\varepsilon= \vert \frac{\gamma}{2} \vert$.  There is an open ball around $\gamma$ such that $\vert f(x)-y \vert \lt \varepsilon$ for all $x$ in that open ball, which means that $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you @RobertShore. I understand that if $f$ is nowhere zero, then $1/f$ is defined, but what implies that this is in the ideal $M$ so that $f \cdot 1/f \in M$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop It sure should. I have a typo there.

Comment: $1/f$ doesn't need to be in the ideal. Did you confuse a definition of an *ideal* with a definition of *subring*?

Comment: Oh yes I did. Since $f \in M$, then $f \cdot 1/f \in M$ also, thus $1 \in M$.

Comment: Yes, indeed....

Comment: I agree with @Podelora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at a point $\gamma$ and nonzero at that point, pick $\epsilon=|f(\gamma)|\gt 0$. Then there is such $\delta\gt 0$ such that, whenever $|x-\gamma|\lt\delta$ it is true that $|f(x)-f(\gamma)|\lt\epsilon=|f(\gamma)|$. Use the triangle inequality to conclude

$$|f(x)|=|f(\gamma)-(f(\gamma)-f(x))|\ge |f(\gamma)|-|f(\gamma)-f(x)|\gt 0$$

so $f(x)$ is also nonzero.

---

As for the map $f=f_{\gamma_1}^2+\ldots+f_{\gamma_n}^2$ i.e. $f(x)=f_{\gamma_1}^2(x)+\ldots+f_{\gamma_n}^2(x)$: the important facts about it:

1. It is obviously nonzero, as sum of squares of some real numbers can only be zero when all of them are zero. On the other hand, at every point on the interval $[0,1]$ at least one of those functions $f_{\gamma_i}$ will be nonzero.
2. Thus, it is a unit (invertible). Its (multiplicative) inverse is just $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$. A reciprocal of a continuous function is continuous wherever defined, i.e. wherever the denominator is nonzero, which in this case is for all $x\in[0,1]$.
3. $f$ is a *finite* linear combination of elements in $M$ (that is why *finiteness* is important!), so is itself in $M$. But, as known from algebra, the only ideal containing a multiplicative unit in a ring is the whole ring.

Comment: So we need the finite subcover condition only to be able to define the map $f=f_{\gamma_1}^2+\ldots+f_{\gamma_n}^2$ in $M$?

Comment: Yes. Ideals are closed for *finite* linear combinations of elements (with "scalars" coming from the whole ring).

Comment: Got it. Slightly unintuitive still so perhaps I should just accept the fact that I couldn't figure this one out myself...

Comment: Give it a thought. It does look like a neat trick, that sum of squares, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, the way I'm thinking about it now is that it's a way to guarantee that we have a function that is never zero in order to be able to state that $1/f$ is a well-defined inverse. It always makes sense when you see someone else doing it hah.

Comment: It is also interesting to see what happens if the interval is not compact. Take the space $C(\mathbb R)$ of all continuous real functions on $\mathbb R$. For a function $f$ you say that it has *compact support* if it is potentially nonzero only within some finite interval $[a,b]$, and is zero outside. Note that all the functions with compact support make up an ideal of $C(\mathbb R)$, which is then necessarily contained in some maximal ideal, and for every real number $x$ there is a function with compact support *not* vanishing at $x$.